# awk command in table update

Tags: unix, awk

Can anyone please help me out for the below condition in awk command

Need to bcp in the file in a table where multiple columns will be there and need to search for a particluar value in all the columns and then if the pattern matches in anyone of the column then that value should be updated in another column n the same table.

```
example: Table A

COL1 COL2 COL3 COL1_AMT  COL2_AMT COL3_AMT FIN_AMT
12    16   17   56.00     78.00    73.00      0.00
```

If COL1 OR COL2 OR COL3 Matches '17' then the corresponding COL_AMT should be updated in another column in the same table.In this case as COL3 = '17' and COL3_AMT 73 should be updated in FIN_AMT column in the same table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you specify how the FIN_AMT should be updated? Which value? Give more examples

Comment: FIN_AMT should be updated with COL3_AMT value.In this case FIN_AMT should be 73.00

Comment: And what if COL1 and COL2 is 17?

Comment: Any one column will match the value as 17.not more than one.

Comment: What does 'bcp' mean ?

Comment: Jesus... why the question has been rollbacked? I edited it to the proper form...

Answer (score 2):

This can make it:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=3;i++) if ($i==17) {$7=$(i+3)}} {print}' file
```

Loops through fields 1 to 3 and if it is 17, then updates the 7th col (FIN_AMT) with `COLi_AMT` value.

#### Test

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=3;i++) if ($i==17) {$7=$(i+3)}} {print}' a
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL1_AMT  COL2_AMT COL3_AMT FIN_AMT
12 16 17 56.00 78.00 73.00 73.00
```

Comment: Errr the text is a bit confusing. From `If COL1 OR COL2 OR COL3 Matches '17' then the corresponding COL_AMT should be updated in another column in the same table.In this case as COL3 = '17' and COL3_AMT 73 should be updated in FIN_AMT column in the same table.` I understood `COLi_AMT` should be updated with `COLi` value.

Comment: No..let me put in this way.COL1--COL1_AMT COL2--COL2_AMT COL3--COL3_AMT.In anyone of the COL1 or COL2 or COL3 '17' will be present.Then the corresponding COL_AMT should be picked and updated in FIN_AMT column. Ex: If COL2 is 17 then COL2_AMT value should be updated in FIN_AMT column.

Answer (score 1):

Awk is your friend

```
awk '{
 for(i=1;i<= ((NF-1)/2));i++) {
   if($i==17) {
    $NF=$(2*i); 
    break;
   }
 }   
}' table.txt
```

This will take the number of fields `NF` value, which is 7 for your given example and iterate through (7-1)/2 = 3 columns, if the actual columns value is 17, it will update the last column with `2*i`-th column, so 2*3 = 6th column value, then it breaks the for cycle (because there wouldn't be any more value 17)

Comment: Let me try this.I have 36 columns for that value '17' and corresponding 36 amount columns.In the final 73rd column i need to update the value.Thank u very much